# How to use DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges in VB.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, scaffolding

How can I use DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges in a VB.NET application in an early development state where the model changes quite often. I know I have to add those lines to Global.asax - but I only found examples using C# - could someone please give me a hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it: global.asax.vb

```
Imports System.Data.Entity
...
Database.SetInitializer(New DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges(Of <ENTITYNAME>)())
```

Answer (score 1):

You should define a class which will be used to initialise your database. I usually call mine DatabaseContextIntializer. This needs to inherit from DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges

The DatabaseContextIntializer class needs to implement the method Seed(YourDataContextClassNameHere context) and you can use this to populate your database when it is initially created.

Comment: Though we are in an very early stage in the development process this is not what we are looking for because every time our model changes we would also have to change the DatabaseContextInitializer to populate the db with example data - but after this weekend we'll surely to this - thanks!